# Filter products by the name entered from the input

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I made a filter by id. I'm trying to make a live filter by the first letters entered from the input, but it doesn't work.

```
const [foodList, setFoodList] = useState(DATA)
const [input, setInput] = useState()

const getInputValue = (event) => {
    setInput(event.target.value)
}

const liveFilter = () => {
    if (isNaN(input) !== false || input !== undefined) {
      // setFoodList(foodList.filter(e => (e.foodName).startsWith(input) === true)) // I tried to write like this but it doesn't work
      setFoodList(foodList.filter(el => el.id === parseInt(input)))
    } 
    if (input === '' || input === undefined) {
      setFoodList(DATA)
    }
    if (input > foodList.length) {
      setFoodList(DATA)
    }
}

useEffect(liveFilter,[input])
```

Also I have a warning in useEffect:  "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'foodList'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. You can also do a functional update 'setFoodList(f => ...)' if you only need 'foodList' in the 'setFoodList' call"

I don't understand how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

Try to use two arrays: one for data source and another for filtered items

```
setFoodList(data_source.filter(e => (e.foodName).startsWith(input, 0) === true))
```